# Airflow - Unable to push templated Env variable in BashOperator to XCom

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to get comfortable with Airflow 2.2 basics on Cloud Composer regarding Xcom and Jinja Templates. My BashOperator's code is the following (it uses the execution date in the name of the file). This filename is passed as an `Env` variable so that `{{ ts }}` is recognised as a template (If I pass it as a `Params` variable, the execution date would not be parsed as `Params` is not templated according to the [source code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/bash.html)):

```
    writeToFile1Bash = BashOperator (
        task_id='writetofile1bash',
        retries=0,
        bash_command='echo "number,square,root\n" > ${file1name} && echo "{{ task_instance.xcom_push(key="file1name", value=$file1name) }}"',
        env={
            'file1name':'/home/airflow/gcs/data/file1-{{ ts }}.txt'
        }
    )
```

The first reference to the variable `${file1name}` is working as expected and, if I finish the bash command there, it will create the file succesfully. However, I would like to be able to pass it as an XCom (with a custom variable name) to downstream tasks and I have not been able to achieve it. I have got the following errors with different formats for extracting the `file1name` variable inside the second command:

-`var.value.file1name` --> **KeyError: 'Variable file1name does not exist'**

-`$(file1name)` or `$file1name` --> **Error rendering template: unexpected char '$' at 101**

-`${file1name}` -->  **jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'**

-`env.file1name`, `env['file1name']` or `ENV['file1name]` --> **env is not defined**

-`params.file1name1` --> **Error rendering template: Object of type StrictUndefined is not JSON serializable**

I have tried every single way I could think of but the documentation is not clear. Even in this [tutorial](https://marclamberti.com/blog/templates-macros-apache-airflow/) (just after the phrase: `So, after modifying the DAG you should have this:`), you are encouraged to use `env` instead of `params` because of the need of Jinja-parsing the variable, however; there is not a code example of how to reference this variable from inside the double brackets {{ }}.

I would highly appreciate if anyone could help to solve this issue as I have spent many hours already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `BashOperator`, the last line to stdout will pushed to xcom.

ref: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.13/_api/airflow/operators/bash_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.bash_operator.BashOperator

You can do it this way:

```
writeToFile1Bash = BashOperator (
    task_id='writetofile1bash',
    retries=0,
    bash_command='echo "number,square,root\n" > ${file1name} && echo $file1name',
    env={
        'file1name':'/home/airflow/gcs/data/file1-{{ ts }}.txt'
    }
)
```

Then in the successive operator:

```
puller = BashOperator(
    task_id='puller',
    bash_command='echo {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="writetofile1bash")}}'
)
```

**Update**

No xcom approach:

`{{ ts }}` is dag_run's timestamp so `ts` won't change between tasks.

That says, it is safe to use `{{ ts }}` multiple times in the same DAG and using static variable you don't have to use xcom.

```py
filename = '/home/airflow/gcs/data/file1-{{ ts }}.txt'

writeToFile1Bash = BashOperator (
    task_id='writetofile1bash',
    retries=0,
    bash_command='echo "number,square,root\n" > ${file1name} && echo $file1name',
    env={
        'file1name': filename
    }
)

puller = BashOperator(
    task_id='puller',
    bash_command=f'echo {filename}'
)
```

Comment: I have tested this workaround and it works, appreciate it a lot! However, I would like to be able to choose the XCom variable name instead of using the default `return_value`. I have edited the description of my question to reflect this. Do you know how to reference the variable inside the double brackets {{ }} in the bash command when doing a `task_instance.xcom_push` with a custom variable name?

Comment: Oh, I see. I know how you can do named key and dynamic value with PythonOperator but I don't know how you can xcom_push a variable within BashOperator.

Comment: I am not sure if you have to use xcom but I included alternative approach without using xcom.  Please check the updadte.  If the place you are intended to use the xcom value is  `template_fields`, you can do this approach.  Otherwise, I think you need `PythonOperator` at least once.

Comment: I think I had ruled out this other approach by mistake because I had confused this kind of variables with the Airflow Variables stored in the meta database and I had followed the general rule of thumb of not storing variable outsides of tasks because of the DAG parsing time (which increases due to connections). I believe that this approach is the best when needing to use the Bash Operator as it will not get stored in the meta database and will still be idempotent for all tasks. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool.   You are right about parsing time that we should be careful what to right outside of operator.  The practice is that you should avoid the large package `import` but defining a constant shouldn't affect in the parsing time.  Even with `{{ts}}`, this is literal string until you pass to operator so `filename = ..` in "Update" is fine practice.