# Passing values between tasks in Airflow (in operators other than PythonOperator

Tags: airflow, jinja2, airflow-xcom

I am trying to see how to pass values between tasks in Airflow.

There are multiple blogs and question in SO, but most of then illustrate this using PythonOperator, where ti.xcom_push and ti.xcom_push are used within the python callable.

**How can we do this inside other operators where we do not have the option of a python callable?**

I tried using what is mentioned as Jinja tempaltes, but I am seeing template render errors.

Example:
This works:
a.

```
'{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="get_fusion_args") }}'
```

But this throws a template error:
b.

```
'{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="get_fusion_args", key="fusion_args") }}'
```

-> I am trying to get the value pushed by a previous task using the key "fusion_args".

**Why is b. throwing a template error (unable to render template)**

I have tried searching for answers including blogs and posts on StackOverflow.
Could not find satisfactory answers.

Reiterating the questions:

1. What ways are available (need some sample code) to pass values between Airflow tasks?
2. What is wrong in the below code? Why is it throwing a jinja template error (cannot render template)
   '{{  ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="get_fusion_args",key="fusion_args) }}'

Answer (score 0):

I found some answers to the questions:

Q1. What ways are available (need some sample code) to pass values between Airflow tasks?
A. [Link1](https://big-data-demystified.ninja/2020/04/15/airflow-xcoms-example-airflow-demystified/) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638295/i-cant-xcom-push-an-arguments-through-bashoperator/54641778) mention how to pull xcom values within BashOperator (i.e., without using a python callable). The same can used with other operators.

Q2. Seems there is nothing wrong in the syntax of ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="get_fusion_args",key="fusion_args). What is wrong is that the pull returns a *LazyXComAccess([1 items])* which is not getting rendered. I found this by printing the value in the earlier step which pushes the xcom. If the push has been a proper value, then the pull step works fine.